# Unable to get custom field

Tags: google-people-api

I try to get a cusotm field from the contacts API.

They custom field is a number and is set for my profile. When I visit https://contacts.google.com/person/me the number is visible. This custom attribute is created via admin.google.com.

But when I try to fetch myself via the People API, with personFields set to **userDefined**,names

I get the name, but not the custom number. I use the OAuth 2.0 way to retrieve the Person.

What do I have to define more to get that custom number? Or is there another way to retrieve a custom attribute from a logged in user (via OAuth 2.0)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify how you create the custom attribute on the Admin console? Also, is this attribute accessible in Contacts? Otherwise, it would make sense that it is not available via People API. It might actually be retrievable via Directory API, if it was added via Admin console https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured the attribute under a different field not under the *userDefined* field. I recommend you use the API again but setting a different personFields until you can obtain the information you want, you can find a list of all valid fields at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get#query-parameters.

For us to provide you with a more fit solution please provide more details (a fullscreen screenshot if possible with dummy data) to better identify how this information can be obtained.

If you are talking about the "Directory profile" section. You can obtain the information using any of the following methods:

- [Admin SDK Directory API] *Users.get* (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) to get the additional information of the user (phones,recoveryPhone,recoveryEmail). Requires API User read privilege.
- [People API] *People.listDirectoryPeople* (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople) to obtain the directory contact information of the domain the user has access to.Requires the directory access to be turned ON for the user.

If you are talking about the custom schemas (Custom attributes) use the [Admin SDK Directory API] *Users.get* or *User.list* (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) to list the custom attributes details of the user(s). You will need to use the **projection** parameter set to **FULL** or **CUSTOM** but specify the exact custom attributes you want in the **customFieldMask** parameter. Requires API User read privilege.